# Sub Report Header not showing in Main Report

Tags: sql, reporting-services, reporting

I have one main report that's calling a sub-report.

Inside this sub report I have a tablix. The tablix size will grow based on the data available in the column grouping.

I have one header above tablix of constant size. I need to show the header on all of the pages, if the first group value contains multiple pages.

Comment: @SathiyaMurthy what have you tried, and what problems did you run in to?

Answer (score 2):

Your question is kind of vague, but to show the header of a tablix on multiple pages, the process is like this:

1. Click the small dropdown arrow at the far right of the "Rows" and "Columns" section in the "Grouping" pane (By default, it's located at the bottom, center of the design window)
2. Click "Advanced Mode"
3. Click the "Static" row grouping for the tablix at the grouping level you want
4. In the Properties section, change the "RepeatOnNewPage" property to "True"

[image]

I hope this helps.

Comment: Hi, i will explain with example.
the report layout like below
Header - some text 
tablix header -
 colA   ColB   colC  colD   colE(this is column Group)
i want the header should be static size. it should not increase or decrease based on tablix column grouping.
if the tablix row reached next page. i need header should repeat. But header will change based on the grouping 
hope this will give you some clear idea.
Thanks,
Sathiyamurthy